# How to use the Maclaurin Series to get $f^{10}(0)$ of $f(x)=(\cos(3x^2)−1)/x^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have no idea how to compute this. Any help is appreciated!
Thank you.

$f^{10}(0)$ of:
$$ f(x)= \frac{\cos(3x^2)−1}{x^2} $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Modify the Maclaurin series for $\cos x$

$$\cos x = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} x^{2k}$$

to compute the Maclaurin series for $\frac 1 {x^2} \Big(1 - \cos(3x^2)\Big)$. Once you've done this, remember that if we have a Maclaurin series for a function $f$, it's given by

$$f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$$

This relates the coefficients of the series with the derivatives of $f$.

Comment: Thank you! sorry but do you mind explaining exactly how to modify it? thats the part that I'm most confused about.

Comment: @user138069 Replace $x$ in the series with $3x^2$; then subtract $1$ and divide.